# Only Accept or Retreive Certiain values in map

Tags: apex, trigger, map, field-update

the below code works to populate a field on the content version with the contentdocumentlink

My issues is that the link returns the user record first then the opportunity, i need the opportunity is there a way that i can restrict the values that go into the map where the Linkedentityid starts with 006 or only retrive those records for the update?

```
    trigger ContentLinkHandoverAttachParentv2 on ContentVersion (After Insert) {
    list<ContentPairs__C> Content = New List<ContentPairs__C>();


         // create a set of all the unique opportunity ids for SOQL below
    Set<id> ContentdocumetIds = new set<id>();

    for (ContentVersion CV1 : Trigger.new){
         ContentdocumetIds.add(CV1.ContentDocumentId);
    }

    System.debug(ContentdocumetIds);

     // create a map so that Opportunity is locatable by its Id (key)
     // 
    Map<string, contentdocumentlink> myMap = new Map<string, contentdocumentlink>(); 

    for(contentdocumentlink objCS : [Select z.linkedentityid, z.contentdocumentid From contentdocumentlink z WHERE contentdocumentid IN :ContentdocumetIds])

    myMap.put(objCS.contentdocumentid, objCS);

    System.debug(myMap);

    For (ContentVersion CV1 :trigger.new){

    contentversion CV2 = [Select id,ContentDocumentId from Contentversion where id = :cv1.Id];
        if(myMap.get(CV2.ContentDocumentId).linkedentityid.getSObjectType() == Schema.Opportunity.getSObjectType()){

        Cv2.AssociatedOppLinkID__c = myMap.get(CV2.ContentDocumentId).linkedentityid;

            update CV2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may or may not have seen this before, but you need to [bulkify your code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code). You've got both a query and a DML inside a for loop. Secondly, you could probably avoid the DML by changing this trigger from "after insert" to "before insert". Third, it appears you're already filtering by opportunity correctly, but if you wanted to be explicit, you could probably change your entire code by adding another database filter and changing some data types. Here's an alternative version of your trigger that should work:

```
trigger ContentLinkHandoverAttachParentv2 on ContentVersion (Before Insert) {
    Map<Id, Id> myMap = new Map<Id, Id>(); 
    for(ContentVersion record: Trigger.new) {
        myMap.put(record.ContentDocumentId, null);
    }
    for(ContentDocumentLink record: [
        SELECT LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId 
        FROM ContentDocumentLink 
        WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :myMap.keySet() AND LinkedEntityId IN
        (SELECT Id FROM Opportunity)
    ]) {
        myMap.put(record.ContentDocumentId, record.LinkedEntityId);
    }
    for(ContentVersion record: Trigger.new) {
        // Assigns null if not an Opportunity, or 006 Id otherwise
        record.AssociatedOppLinkId__c = myMap.get(record.ContentDocumentId);
    }
}
```

---

Due to "implementation limits", it looks like the query had to be modified to include a subquery filter.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but its taken me back to one of the origninal limitations

Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.

any ideas how to get around this one in the format you have provided?

Comment: @user37980 I realized I had a mistake in my code, but the compiler doesn't seem to honor the rules of the content restriction. I think this is a bug, because the SOQL query window allows the same type of query.

Comment: @user37980 I think I found an appropriate alternative, at least it compiles in my org. Give it a try.

Comment: This compiles but doesnt achive the desired result, my previos code works but only for the records added after the first it looks like for some reason the record created first surfaces the user linked id and the records added after surfaces the opp link first. odd if i query the first added record it returns the user and opp link perhaps i could force an update once its been inserted and try to find the opp link

Comment: Using your subquery solution in my original code to filter the opp i can now make sure the opp records are pulled into the map instead of the user in the first instance